# Doxygen support for Python in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, doxygen, comments

It seems to me that doxymacs only supports C/C++. Are there any tools for auto/semi-auto doxygen documentation for Python codes in Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) and have been loving it. It supports both auto-gen documentation (embedded comments, supporting rst if that's your cup of tea) and manual documentation. Put 'em together and you've got yourself a nice little doc package that's super easy to set up.

I prefer native tools (Sphinx) for Python documentation to doxygen, which is great for documentation, but can be a real headache to set up for some languages.

Comment: Thanks, Demian. Yeah, I am aware of Sphinx, although not digging deep enough. It seems not supporting C/C++ very well. I, like many others, use different programming languages on a daily basis. Thus, a language-across documentation tool with consistent behaviour is so nice. Disappointingly, I haven't found one.